# User define type not defined - from custom class module

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues with this "User defined type not defined" error. I have never had this error before until now that i add a custom class module to my workbook. I don't have any type... end type pieces of code in the workbook. I read that when you have something like `dim s as Strig` instead of `dim s as String` you will get this error. but i don't have any thing like that in my code. But reading this leads me to believe that since i have added my class module i have something like `dim h as Holidays` where Holidays is the name of my class, i am getting this error because excel cant reference this to a type?

i have also read that the from many of these posts about the same error that people are fixing them with by adding a reference. will i'm just creating a class module. i shouldn't need any other references should i? any ways here is a screen shot of the references i have already.

[image]

What could i be doing wrong with this class module? i have even tried all my instances of `dim h as Holidays` to `dim h as Object` with no luck. i will post how i am using my code so maybe some one can see what is going on.

Thanks in advance for yalls help. the baffling thing is everything still works as intended, just get this error every time our change event runs.

Here is how i initialize my instance: i will be leaving out some of the unrelated code

```
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim d As Date
Dim startRange As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim highMonths As Integer
Dim h As Holidays
Dim y As Integer
Dim a()

startDate = DateValue(Range("Forecast_ProStart"))
y = year(startDate)
Set h = factory.CreateHolidays(y)
```

here is my factory module:

```
Function CreateHolidays(year As Integer) As Holidays
    Set CreateHolidays = New Holidays
    CreateHolidays.setHolidays year
End Function
```

(the class returns information about our holidays, it has functions like that are called like h.getMonthWorkingDays(args))

and then the class: getDate() is a function in the class that isn't related

```
Public NewYears As Date
Public MemorialDay As Date
Public IndependenceDay As Date
Public LaborDay As Date
Public Thanksgiving As Date
Public ThanksgivingAfter As Date
Public ChristmasEve As Date
Public ChristmasDay As Date
Private varYear As Integer
Private allDays As New Collection

Sub setHolidays(hYear As Integer)
    varYear = hYear
    Dim d As Date

    'fixed days
    NewYears = DateValue("1/1/" & varYear)
    IndependenceDay = DateValue("7/4/" & varYear)
    ChristmasEve = DateValue("12/24/" & varYear)
    ChristmasDay = DateValue("12/25/" & varYear)

    d = DateValue("5/1/" & varYear)
    MemorialDay = getDate(d, vbMonday, 7)
    d = DateValue("9/1/" & varYear)
    LaborDay = getDate(d, vbMonday, 1)
    d = DateValue("11/1/" & varYear)
    Thanksgiving = getDate(d, vbThursday, 4)
    ThanksgivingAfter = DateAdd("d", 1, Thanksgiving)

    allDays.Add (NewYears)
    allDays.Add (MemorialDay)
    allDays.Add (IndependenceDay)
    allDays.Add (LaborDay)
    allDays.Add (Thanksgiving)
    allDays.Add (ThanksgivingAfter)
    allDays.Add (ChristmasEve)
    allDays.Add (ChristmasDay)

End Sub
```

Comment: If you copy your Class module to a new workbook and add a regular module which just has a declaration `Dim h As Holidays` does that project compile?  Also make sure you have "break in class module" set in your VBA error handling preferences, or you may not see the root cause of your errors.

Comment: @TimWilliams this was a great idea, the answer was in a new workbook it did not throw the error. so i commented out the whole module that used my class module, and it no longer threw the error. i added back only one line, dim h as Holidays and it continues to throw the error on a worksheet change event, but only once. (after it throws the error it will not throw it again until i leave the sheet and come back to run the change event again) I am at a lost for why this interaction causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i after hours of troubleshooting, i believe to have resolved my issue for any one that cares.

I had a module with a sub in it called ExportSFCForecast (was completely unrelated to the code and question above) and then added the new sub to the same module, which contained the `dim h as Holidays` , titled ComputeForecast. I ended up changing the name of ExportSFCForecast to something like cast. And now the error no longer pops up after a worksheet selection change. I've tired as much as i can do to recreate the error again but it appears to be fixed.

I will never understand why this fixed it but it did. Maybe it was with the way excel loads it's module subs, or something was interfering because both names contained the word forecast? i don't know but its working now.